# Как правильно переписать сеттер в наследуемом классе, чтобы вместо числа в карточке выводилось изображение?

Tags: javascript, ооп, классы

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно переписать сеттер в наследуемом классе, чтобы вместо чисел в карточке выводились изображения?

```
class Card {
 _cardNumber = null;
 _opennedCard = false;
 _successfulCard = false

 constructor(container, cardNumber, flip) {
  this.cardNumber = cardNumber

  container.append(this.createElement(flip))
 }

createElement(action) {
    const card = document.createElement('div');
    card.classList.add('card');

    card.textContent = this.cardNumber;

    card.addEventListener('click', () => {
      card.classList.add('openned');

      this._opennedCard = true;

      action(card)
    })

    return card;
  }

  set cardNumber(value) {
    this._cardNumber = value
  }

  get cardNumber() {
    return this._cardNumber
  }

  set open(value) {
    this._opennedCard = value
  }

  get open() {
    return this._opennedCard
  }

  set success(value) {
    this._successfulCard = value
  }

  get success() {
    return this._successfulCard
  }
}
```

Наследуемый класс:

```
class AmazingCard extends Card {
  set cardNumber(value) {
    const cardsImgArray = [
      './img/водопад.jpg',
      './img/глаз.jpg',
      './img/зонтик.jpg',
      './img/кот.jpg',
      './img/олень.jpg',
      './img/павлин.jpg',
      './img/пейзаж.jpg',
      './img/цветок.jpg'
    ];

    const img = document.createElement('img');
    img.classList.add('img-card');
    img.src = cardsImgArray[value];

    this.createElement(this.flip).append(img)
  }
}
```

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Вы в сеттере не сохраняете значения никуда. Надо сохранить полученный результат в переменную. Так же создать геттер, который вернет данный результат, либо вызвать внутренний метод, который отрисует новое значение